# How to overload copy and paste event for QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlineedit

I need to change copy and paste events for `QLineEdit`. For example, we have line "This line" and I want to delete "i" symbols - "Ths lne".
How can I get this result?

I tried to inherit from QLineEdit and overload copy() and paste() slots like this:

```
class CTextField : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CTextField(QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual ~CTextField() = default;

public slots:
    virtual void paste();
    virtual void copy();
};
```

But slots don't invoke when I paste using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or by menu item. The same is true for copying.

Comment: Why do you don't connect to `void QLineEdit::textChanged(const QString &text)` signal? Do what you want with the line edit text in the slot when text is changed.

Comment: @AlexanderTrotsenko how can "textChanged" signal help me for copy event?

Comment: The reason why `paste()` and `copy()` do not work is because they are not virtual in `QLineEdit`. You could see that if you used `override` in your `CTextField::copy()`. In other words: you cannot override them.

There is `QTextEdit::createMimeDataFromSelection()` and `https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#insertFromMimeData()` which allows overriding and does what you probably need. But this API is not available for `QLIneEdit`. So maybe you could use `QTextEdit` instead of it?

Comment: You can also look at `https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#clipboard` to track changes in the application clipboard (copy operation only).

Answer (score 0):

For myself I found solution in reimplementation of all ways of slots `QLineEdit::copy()` and `QLineEdit::paste()` could be called: by key sequences, popup `QMenu` and `mouseReleaseEvent`. This should be enough for most cases.

**CLineEdit.h**

```
class CLineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT

protected:
    virtual void contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event) override
    {
        if (QMenu *menu = createStandardContextMenu()) {
            for (auto * action : menu->actions())
            {
                if (disconnect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(copy())))
                    connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(cleanCopy()));
                if (disconnect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(paste())))
                    connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(cleanPaste()));
            }
            menu->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
            menu->popup(event->globalPos());
        }
    }

    virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) override
    {
        if (event == QKeySequence::Copy)
            cleanCopy();
        else if (event == QKeySequence::Paste)
        {
            QClipboard::Mode mode = QClipboard::Clipboard;
            if (event->modifiers() == (Qt::CTRL | Qt::SHIFT)
                    && event->key() == Qt::Key_Insert)
                mode = QClipboard::Selection;
            cleanPaste(mode);
        }
        else if (event == QKeySequence::Cut)
            cleanCut();
        else
            QLineEdit::keyPressEvent(event);
    }

    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* e)
    {
        if (e->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
            cleanCopy(QClipboard::Selection);
        else if (!d->control->isReadOnly() && e->button() == Qt::MiddleButton) 
        {
            deselect();
            cleanPaste(QClipboard::Selection);
        }
        else
            QLineEdit::mouseReleaseEvent(e);
    }


protected slots:
    virtual void cleanCopy(QClipboard::Mode mode = QClipboard::Clipboard)
    {
        // Your copy implementation
    }
    virtual void cleanPaste(QClipboard::Mode mode = QClipboard::Clipboard)
    {
        // Your paste implementation
    }
    virtual void cleanCut(QClipboard::Mode mode = QClipboard::Clipboard)
    {
        // Your cut implementation OR just:
        if (hasSelectedText())
        {
            cleanCopy();
            del();
        }
    }
};
```